# downstream project could not be found in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, devops, cicd

I am trying to trigger my ui automation project pipeline from my frontend project pipeline also I am using my company's GitLab account and the trigger job is showing **'downstream project could not be found'** both the projects are in the same group called feedback-app

i am sharing some part of my gitlab yml file of feedback-app-frontend project as I cannot share everything for security reasons

```
stages:
  - cleanup
  - stage-build
  - stage-docker
  - stage-ui-automation
  - stage-deploy
  - prod-build
  - prod-docker
  - prod-deploy

stage_ui_automatoin:
  stage: stage-ui-automation
  trigger:
    project: feedback-app/feedback-app-automation
    strategy: depend
```

also when I open my project the url in the browser is like 'https://gitlab.mycompanyname.com/feedback-app/feedback-app-automation'
I am not understanding if I have given the wrong path or if is there any access issue

group - feedback-app

projects

- feedback-app-automation - owner access
- feedback-app-frontend - developer access

any kind of help is appreciated.